# Error while trying to run mountebank

Tags: mountebank

Getting the below error when try to run/start mountebank using the imposter file.

**Installed package versions,**

npm : 5.6.0

node : 8.10.0

mountebank : 1.14.0

**Command use to start mountebank:**

*mb --configfile imposter.ejs --allowInjection*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a JSON formatting error in your imposter file. Try copying it into https://jsonlint.com/ for help. If it's templatized, I'd recommend excising parts of it at a time until you can locate the part where the syntax error lies.